# Fixed Navigation - no scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi currently doing a quick website, got the header and toggle navigation in place, however due to the fact the nav bar is fixed it wont allow scrolling on the nav if the navbar is taller than the height of the screen, tried the overflow: scroll and position relative but cannot seem to find a work around, appreciate any assistance provided.

```js
function NavToggle() {
  var tn = document.getElementById("nav-bar")
  if(tn.style.display === "none"){
    tn.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    tn.style.display = "none";       
  }    
}
```

```css
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;    
 }

html, body{    
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header and Navigation */

header{
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #222;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav{
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.title-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

/* menu base styles */

nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li{
  height: 50px;
}

.title-wrapper>a{    
  font-size: 16px;
}

a{
  color: #999;
}


nav a{
  text-decoration: none;   
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 10px; 
}

nav a:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

/* Menu Toggle Styling */

.menu-toggle{
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;    
  padding: 0 15px 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;    
}

.menu-toggle-button{
  padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-wrapper header-container">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <a class="a-tag header-title">Chemical Finger Print Analysis</a>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <span id="menu-toggle-button" onclick="NavToggle()">&#9776;</span>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>                        
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `overflow-y: auto;max-height: 100vh;` to `.header` like this:

```js
function NavToggle() {
    var tn = document.getElementById("nav-bar")
    if(tn.style.display === "none"){
        tn.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        tn.style.display = "none";       
    }    
}
```

```css
html, body{    
    overflow-y: auto;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/* Header and Navigation */

header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

nav {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
}

.title-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* menu base styles */

nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav li{
    height: 50px;
}

.title-wrapper>a{    
    font-size: 16px;
}

a{
    color: #999;
}


nav a{
    text-decoration: none;   
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 10px; 
}

nav a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}

/* Menu Toggle Styling */

.menu-toggle{
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;    
    padding: 0 15px 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;    
}

.menu-toggle-button{
    padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-wrapper header-container">
            <div class="header-wrapper">
                <div class="title-wrapper">
                    <a class="a-tag header-title">Chemical Finger Print Analysis</a>
                    <div class="menu-toggle">
                        <span id="menu-toggle-button" onclick="NavToggle()">&#9776;</span>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <nav id="nav-bar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>                        
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks was stuck on this for about 4 hours, appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You have made the entire `<header>` fixed but you need to make `title-wrapper` as fixed, Here is working code

```js
function NavToggle() {
  var tn = document.getElementById("nav-bar")
  if (tn.style.display === "none") {
    tn.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    tn.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header and Navigation */

header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #222;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.title-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #222222;
}


/* menu base styles */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  height: 50px;
}

.title-wrapper>a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  color: #999;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Menu Toggle Styling */

.menu-toggle {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 15px 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-toggle-button {
  padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-wrapper header-container">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <a class="a-tag header-title">Chemical Finger Print Analysis</a>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <span id="menu-toggle-button" onclick="NavToggle()">&#9776;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```